# ¿Cómo configurar rutas de laravel después de haber clonado un proyecto?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema cuando clono mi proyecto de laravel el cual lo ocupo como api, instalo el composer para que trabaje pero al momento de querer entrar a una ruta me manda un error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

ya ejecutaste el comando `php artisan key:generate` ?
adicional, si estas usandolo como api y estas usando jwt debes de ejecutar en la terminal `php artisan jwt:secret`

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias!
Si, ya los ejecute, pero aún me sigue marcando ese error

Comment: existe el archivo .env?

Comment: Si, si existe y la conexión a la base si es la correcta

Comment: pasa con todas tus rutas?

Comment: Estuve buscando y hay personas que les ha pasado el mismo error, varias han tenido el problema por el orden en que tienen las rutas, cuando tienen el mismo nombre trata de crear las que no tienen parametro primero, y sin parametro después, además, si estas usando tu proyecto como una API recuerda que las rutas que se encuentran en .web son las que reconocera el navegador sin anteceder '/api', pero si solo tienes rutas en .api debes probarla a traves de postman por ejemplo

Comment: Si, me funciono justo eso, copiar las que no necesitan parámetros y luego poner las que si tienen parámetros. Gracias!